# is there any text configuration file exists in android?

Tags: android, performance

I have developed an application based on smartphone's sensors data.If i want to manage  output data of application by run one text file in java code which will configure all data such as time duration and crate automatically after stored some fixed data etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create an XML file in your res/values forlder (for example config.xml or etc) and declare your configs there , then access them from your java code :)
See this link for more info :
[developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html)